# xslt debugging keeps debugging previous version of xslt document VS 2012

Tags: debugging, xslt, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to debug an xslt file in VS2012. When I hit XML -> Xslt Debugging at the top it keeps on showing the output from a previous version I debugged. I've many many changes to it since then and it's not reflecting that.

Here is a screenout :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKXRA.jpg

The code in my xslt file (which i'm pointing the input to an XML file)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select ="CommercialClients">

                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CommercialClients">
        I found some data
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What happens if you simply delete the old output file?

Comment: If you are referring to the temp debug output file located in my Temp folder in Users, I have tried to delete that but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: When you use XML->XSLT debugging, is the selected tab the XML file, or the XSLT file?

Comment: Could you post the contents of the XML file you're running it on?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i1LvfrGy - Also note i've deleted the temp folder from Users/Appdata/Local/Temp folder and i've also tried to delete some debug files. I just don't understand how on earth it's retaining the previous debug. Makes 0 sense.

Comment: This is the debug output log. http://pastebin.com/8abhRnqv

Comment: I does seem like everything's in order. Have you tried creating a separate XSLT file, pasting the contents over, and running that?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, I have now and it has thrown an error this time. http://pastebin.com/fLwVkpPG

Comment: Also in the xslt page, the first line `code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
`code` the "xml" part is highlighted red and it says "Unable to connect to the remote server". Basically, this is an ongoing uni assignment i'm doing, first part was to create a page that uses a class library and extracts data from an SQL database, now this part is to play about with XML, but as you can see it's not going too well for me :(

Comment: That's weird.  There's another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013127/getting-an-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server-warning-on-xsl-element) with exactly the same issue, but no answers.  Have you tried restarting visual studio?

Comment: Just did now, made no difference

Comment: Im about 40 minutes, I'm going to try this on my laptop. Take the whole solution over including the new file I just made and see if it works or not.